# How can I mount a tmpfs without root?

Tags: linux, unix

I'm on a managed machine but I'd like to create a folder stored in RAM for temporary storage, how might I do this?

Comment: These days you should be able to pull it off without `sudo`, using PolicyKit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't create a new tmpfs mount without root privileges.

However, many Linux distos provide a tmpfs mount on `/dev/shm` that's writable by all users. If it's there, you should be able to <strike>abuse</strike> use that to store your temporary directory.

On RHEL4/RHEL5:

```
[me@home]$ mount | grep tmpfs
none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
```

On Ubuntu 11.10, it is mounted on `/run/shm`:

```
[me@ubuntu_home]$  mount | grep shm
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

Comment: I'm on Scientific Linux which I believe is a spin of RHEL so /dev/shm is working wonderfully well, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Without the help of a sysadmin you can't. In fact you need him to use sudo to make you able to mount tmpfs or to put an ad-hoc entry in /etc/fstab .

The point is that mount requires special rights.

Ask your sysadmin

PS: if your system works with tmpfs mounted on /tmp, then you can create a folder there.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that there usually is a tmpfs mounted in world writable /tmp

Comment: /tmp is not in memory unfortunately